# JS SDK facebook API pass access token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, laravel

```
    $scope.getProfilePicture_180=function(token){
  var res={};
      Facebook.api(
            '/me',
            'GET',
            {"fields":"picture.width(180).height(180),name,last_name,middle_name","access_token":token},
            function (response) {
                res=response;
            }
          );
      return res;
      }
```

In the contrary this is following code works  for me,What I can't do is use the above "**Fields** " thing

```
                         Facebook.api('/me?access_token='+accessToken, function(response) {
                         $scope.bigData=response;

                      });
```

for this js code,Passing the access token is not working what is the right way to pass access token to a facebook api call on the above function

Comment: Is it really not working? As you may have facing issue due to async behavior! Check again

Comment: It is not working for me but the following ,"I will edit the post " is working

Answer (score 1):

One point of using an SDK is that you do not need to worry about the Access Token. After authorization, the Token will get used anyway, so you can just try this instead:

```
FB.api(
    '/me',
    {fields: 'picture.width(180).height(180),name,last_name,middle_name'},
    function (response) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Comment: oh I was wondering,Why I have to pass it every time. as the doc says. wait let me check.

Comment: I miss read it,accesstoken for every request but here it is implicitly ,thanks bro it worked.

Comment: you´re welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer, let´s keep stackoverflow clean ;)